# How can I draw different elements in perspective?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator

[image]

Can someone explain how is the below image created?

I am specially interested in background grid. I am comfortable with the sphere. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not difficult, there must be a few ways to do it, but this is how I'd do it:

- Create a new layer and draw the rectangles first using the `Rectangle Tool`. You can start with a single shape and then duplicate it. Elements with the same opacity can be merged, but if you need some with some opacity, keep those separated.
- Once you are happy with your '2D' result, turn everything into a `Smart Object` so it
  s easier to work with.
- Go to `Edit > Transform > Distort`, and play with the corners of the big rectangle so it imitates the perspective. You can also use `Perspective` and `Skew`. The easiest way to understand what the perspective should look like is to use an example like the one you have. Imagine you trace lines, what kind of shape is it compared to a rectangle? You will need to 'transformations': One that makes the shape stretch, and one that makes the upper part shorter than the bottom (things in the distance look smaller than things that are close). For this last one, you can use `Warp`.

[image]

Voila!

Comment: will try out and let you know. Thanks for your response.

Answer (score 2):

Also, for the curved lines:

- Make a path with the desired curvature using the pen tool
- Right click > stroke path (make sure you're using an appropriate brush, and don't stimulate pressure)
- Use the same perspective distort Yisela used for the grid until you have the desired image. You could also do some light burning/dodging (or any other contrast tool) to give some perspective.